# Django Update View not saving

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

In order to use UpdateView without pk in the url, I override the get_object function, however, when I test it, the form is not saved. 
There are two models involved: user and Profile, with a OnetoOne relation.

My url is as following:

```
url(r'^profile/edit/$', profileviews.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(template_name="Pages_Profile/profileupdate.html"),name="profileupdate_URL"),
```

And the view class is:

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
   model = Profile
   form_class = UserProfileForm

   def get_object(self, queryset=None):
       return get_object_or_404(self.model, user=self.request.user)

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I think the problem lays on the view, but I can't figure out. 
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called `django-braces` which includes a whole bunch of very useful generic view mixins to help with using Django CBV (class based views):

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
   model = Profile
   form_class = UserProfileForm

   def get_object(self, queryset=None):
       return get_object_or_404(self.model, user=self.request.user)
```

You can find more about it [here](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.2/).